# Creating multiple instances of a subclass, with only one instance of a superclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to implement the Flyweight pattern, but I'm not quite sure how inheritance works, and so I'm not quite sure how this pattern works.

Let's say I have a superclass that holds all the "heavy" information - textures, etc., the instrinsic information (the one that never changes).

```
class Block{
public: //for the sake of the example
Texture tex; 
etc.
};
```

And I have the light class with data that changes:

```
class Block_light : public Block {
public:
int posX, posY, posZ;
int color;
etc.
};
```

So, if I in main create n `Block_light`, will I be also creating n `Block` or will they all be tied to one instance?

```
 int main(){
 std::vector<Block_light> blocks(n);
 return 0;
 };
```

Did I create n `Block_light` and 1 `Block` or n `Block_light` and n `Block`? If it's the latter, how can I make it so that it only uses one instance?

Comment: In your example, there is no relation between `Block` and `Block_light`. If `Block_light` inherits from `Block` you will create `n` of them.

Comment: Yeah, a typo. So, how do I make it so it only creates 1 Block?

Comment: Due to the inheritance you can't. Every `Block_light` object *is a* `Block` object as well.

Comment: Do not let it inherit. Inheritance will make the subclass large enough to contain an object of the superclass. Probably there should be a reference/pointer/`shared_ptr` to `Block` in `Block_light`. What is most appropriate depends heavily on your use-case. (Beware static variables, they will have a runtime overhead due to implicit threading checks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ object model ensures that each instance of a subclass (i.e. *derived* class) [contains](https://web.archive.org/web/20190614050234/http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/inheritance.html) also its own instances of all its superclasses (i.e. *base* classes).

In your case, this means that every `Block_light` object will have all the `Block_light` properties, as well as a `Block` sub-object with all the `Block` properties. In other words, `Block_light` are not so light at all.

If you want to share a single common state:

- You could [use composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance): the `Block_light` would not inherit from `Block` but refer to a shared `Block` object.
- If you nevertheless need to be able to use `Block` and `Block_light` interchangeably,  you could make both inherit from a common interface (i.e. a clss with only virtual functions and no state) `IBlock`.
- You could alternatively use the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), in which parts of the state (shared or not) is "externalized" into an extrinsinc state. The particularity of this pattern is that the reference to the extrinsic state is provided to the classes functions by the caller, so that the flyweight object does not need to store a pointer to such a state.

The first option would look like:

```
class Block {...}; 
class Block_light {       // no inheritance 
    shared_ptr<Block> b;  // but (private) composition   
    ...
};
```

The second option would be:

```
class IBlock {  // no member variables
public:
    virtual Texture get_texture()=0;
    virtual ~IBlock(){}; 
};  

class Block : public IBlock {  // sharable state
    Texture tex; 
public: 
    Texture get_texture() override { return tex; }
};    

class Block_light : public IBlock {
    shared_ptr<IBlock> b;  // or IBlock or Block depending on the needs.  
public:
    Block_light (shared_ptr<IBlock>i) : b(i) {}
    Texture get_texture() override { return b->get_texture(); }
};  

int main() { // just a perfectible quick example
    auto myb=make_shared<Block>();
    Block_light b1(myb);
    b1.get_texture();
}
```

The last one would be used like this:

```
int main() { // just a perfectible quick example
    Block myb;     // shared part; 
    Block_light bl;
    bl.get_texture(myb);
}
```

I will not enter into the details of the flyweight implementation but you have [an example here](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html).  However think twice before opting for this pattern, since providing the shared context can be challenging and error prone.

Comment: FWIW the first link ('contains') requires authentication to access. I no longer have Fermi creds.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for notifying me of this change.  The article had some interesting schemas to visualize the principles.  I have updated the link to use the wayback machine to point to the article as it was at the time I answered.

Answer (score 0):

What you implemented isn't the lightweight pattern. There is no such thing as `Block_light`, but rather `Block` would be a pure interface to an implementation provided by something like `Block1` which looks like what your `Block` definition looks like.

E.g.:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

class BlockState {
public:
    int posX, posY, posZ;
    int color;
};

struct Texture {
    Texture(const std::string &);
    char data[8196];
};

class Block {
public:
    Block(std::string) {};
    virtual void render(const BlockState &state) const = 0;
};

class Block1 final : public Block {
public:
    Block1(std::string name) : Block(name), tex(name) {};
    void render(const BlockState &state) const override;
private:
    const Texture tex;
};

class BlockFactory final {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<const Block> getBlock(const std::string &key) {
        auto it = dict.find(key);
        if(it != dict.end()) return it->second;
        auto it2 = dict.try_emplace(key, std::make_shared<Block1>(key));
        return it2.first->second;
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<const Block>> dict;
};

void render () {
    static BlockFactory factory;
    BlockState a, b;
    factory.getBlock("brick")->render(a);
    factory.getBlock("brick")->render(b);
}
```

`BlockFactory` is managing instances of `Block` for you, implemented by the not visible `Block1` implementation. Use a different factory for testing etc, and you can just switch the implementation below for sake of testing as you like.

Your "per instance" state is not inheriting from `Block`, but is rather kept separate and by value, where as the `Block` instances are owned by `BlockFactory` and only passed by reference / pointer.